# Django + Vue.js importing modules

Tags: javascript, html, django, vue.js, ckeditor

How can I import modules for VueJS app in a template, rendered by Django. I'm trying to import module CKEditor.
This is my situation:

*`template.html`*:

```
<div id="app">
    <form>
        <vue-ckeditor v-model="formField" />
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-ckeditor2"></script>
<script>
Vue.component('vue-ckeditor', VueCkeditor.VueCkeditor)
var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            formField: "",
        }
    },
</script>
```

On [Github](https://github.com/dangvanthanh/vue-ckeditor2) it requires `import VueCkeditor from 'vue-ckeditor2';`.

Is there a way to do that in a Django template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i understood is you want to import a component and use it in your template.

try this:-

```
var VueCkeditor  = require(vue-ckeditor2);

    var app = new Vue({
         components: { VueCkeditor : VueCkeditor },
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        el: '#app',
        data: function() {
            return {
                formField: "",
            }
        },
    </script>
```

edit:-
try this:-

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-ckeditor2@2.0.7/dist/vue-ckeditor2.js"></script>
 var app = new Vue({
// the component is exported inside defult 
components: { VueCkeditor : VueCkeditor.default },
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        el: '#app',
        data: function() {
            return {
                formField: "",
            }
        },
    </script>
```

Comment: changed const to var , as its es5

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to implement the CK Editor into my form. It's made for rich text editing in HTML.
Nor require or include are defined, so I get an error: ReferenceError: require is not defined.

Comment: understood, i was unaware that you dont have require. so first we need to check whether this script is providing a global variable or not.

Comment: changed the code, the latest version does not support without require.
so may be the syntax for using it will also defer

Comment: Yes. I got it work now. I have to edit some styles, but otherwise, thank you very much!